# How to make Selenium and django use the same database

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm a newbie in the use of Selenium.

And I got a problem using it.
If I understand correctly, when I run my test suite (./manage.py test), django will create a new database for run the test suite.
But if I include Selenium test in those test suite, it seems that Selenium connect to my server and access to my real database, which make my test failed.

What I'm trying to do is either be able to use the real database with django test or be able to use  test database with Selenium.

Is there a solution to my problem ?

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Visit
#SELENIUM
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

# Create your tests here.
from django.test import TestCase

# Faker
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker(['fr'])

def test_connect(driver):
    driver.get("http://demo.localhost:8000/")
    title = driver.title
    
    username = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="login")
    password = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="password")
    submit_button = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="button[type='submit']")

    username.send_keys("demo")
    password.send_keys("demo")
    submit_button.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//p[contains(text(),'Aucun dossier ou fichier')]")        

class VisitCreationTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
        test_connect(self.driver)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_login(self):

        self.driver.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value="Créer une visite").click()

        form = self.driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="createVisitForm")

        name = form.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="name")
        description = form.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="description")
        
        company_name = fake.company()
        name.send_keys(company_name)
        
        company_description = fake.text()
        description.send_keys(company_description)
        
        submit = form.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="input[type='submit']")
        submit.click()
        # assert Visit.objects.filter(name=company_name, description=company_description).exists()
        print(Visit.objects.filter(name=company_name, description=company_description).exists())
        return
```

Comment: Share related code of your tests. It's almost never ok if something tests using a real database.

Comment: @NixonSparrow yes I did edit my post and added my entire code and the problem appear on the print at the bottom, my terminal send me this error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "visit_visit" does not exist` whereas when I take a look at my objects in the real database, the object is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting to the real server:

```
driver.get("http://demo.localhost:8000/")
```

No wonder that you are using real database, because you are entering real site. You need to use `live_server_url` and instead of `TestCase`, use i.e. `StaticLiveServerTestCase`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase

class VisitCreationTestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def check_connect(self, driver):
        driver.get(self.live_server_url)
        ...

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        ...
        self.check_connect(self.driver)

    def test_login(...):
        ...
```

You can find some nice practice help with [Obey testing goat](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/).